# How to display ping information of a server on the stage in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ping, stage, dynamic-text

so I have a code to ping a server, but it traces the information. I want to change that, and use dynamic text to display that ping information on the stage. How would I do that? Here is my code:

```
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
ldr.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, ldrStatus);

var url:String = "URL-TO-SITE";
var limit:int = 10;

var time_start:Number;
var time_stop:Number;
var times:int;

ping();

function ping():void
{
    trace("pinging", url);

    times = 0;
    doThePing();
}

function doThePing():void
{
    time_start = getTimer();
    ldr.load(new URLRequest(url));
}

function ldrStatus(evt:*):void
{
    if(evt.status == 200)
    {
        time_stop = getTimer();
        trace("got response in", time_stop - time_start, "ms");
    }

    times++;
    if(times < limit) doThePing();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you are asking, but if you want to show the information that is being traced right now, you have to have a textfield on the stage, or create one dynamically. You could do it like this you want to make a text field:

```
import flash.text.TextField;

function ldrStatus(evt:*):void{

    if(evt.status == 200)
    {
        time_stop = getTimer();
        trace("got response in", time_stop - time_start, "ms");

        var tf:TextField = new TextField();
        addChild(tf);
        tf.text = "got response in"+ (time_stop - time_start) + "ms";
    }

    times++;
    if(times < limit) doThePing();
}
```

Comment: just replace the ldrStatus() function with your own.

Comment: I replaced, it and it doesn't work :( I have the information of the ping, but I just want to display that information on a dynamic text box on the stage.

Comment: I just basically want to display the trace in a dynamic text box

Comment: I don't see a problem with Michell's code: it would probably help if you tell us the error you are seeing.

Comment: do you get the trace? If so, you should see a textfield in upper left corner with the message.

Answer (score 0):

It worked, I just made a text box on the stage called textBox, and added some code to the end.

```
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
ldr.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, ldrStatus);

var url:String = "http://google.com.net";
var limit:int = 10;

var time_start:Number;
var time_stop:Number;
var times:int;

ping();

function ping():void
{
    trace("pinging", url);

    times = 1;
    doThePing();
}

function doThePing():void
{
    time_start = getTimer();
    ldr.load(new URLRequest(url));
}

function ldrStatus(evt:*):void
{
    if(evt.status == 200)
    {
        time_stop = getTimer();
        textBox.text = String("got response in", time_stop - time_start, "ms");
    }


}
```